# How does Xcode load the main storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I create a new single view application in Xcode 4.6 using storyboard, we can see that the main function creates a new application using the application delegate like this:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```

However if we look at MyAppDelegate.h and MyAppDelegate.m, there is nowhere in the code that references MainStoryboard.storyboard. This differs from a non-storyboard version where we can find the line of code that loads the nib file programmatically.

So my question is, how does the storyboard get loaded? (where should I poke to find it?)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Look at your Target settings for the Project

[image]

Notice the Main Storyboard setting.

If you wanted to do this in code yourself, you would do something like.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

   // Set root view controller and make windows visible
   self.window.rootViewController = vc;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];` before `self.window.rootViewController = vc;`

Answer (score 9):

Give a look to the *UIApplicationMain* discussion:

> Discussion
>   This function instantiates the application object from the principal class and instantiates the delegate (if any) from the given class and sets the delegate for the application. It also sets up the main event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing events. If the application’s Info.plist file specifies a main nib file to be loaded, by including the NSMainNibFile key and a valid nib file name for the value, this function loads that nib file.

When *UIApplicationMain* gets called, a plist file containing all the application info is loaded:

[image]

That's how it "understands" that the xib/storyboard file needs to get loaded.

Answer (score 8):

It is started from the UIMainStoryboardFile setting from your info.plist file. Xcode then creates a main window, instantiates your first view controller, and adds it to the window. You can still do this in code similar to the .nib using

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* initialView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode, the human-readable Info.plist section that determines the main storyboard is:

`Main storyboard file base name`

In plain text, the key is `UIMainStoryboardFile`:

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to instantiate with Swift

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
var vc : AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
self.window!.rootViewController = vc as UIViewController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: If you want to initialize the storyboard in the `applicationDidFinishLoading` method in `AppDelegate`, you also have to create the `window` object. For example like this `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)`

Comment: you should use let instead of var and use ? instead of ! (even when you're sure), there's no real penalty to it

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 11.3.1, changing **Main storyboard file base name** alone is not enough, there's a **Storyboard Name** configuration in the **Application Scene Manifest** that should also be changed as well.

```
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Home</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: After a break from iOS development I completely missed out on the UIScene stuff. This comment helped me get sane unit testing back.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but you can get to the viewController from the window as shown below

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        var viewController = window?.rootViewController as? ViewController
        if let viewController = viewController {
            // do awesome stuff
        }

        return true
    }
}
```